# How can I calculate what the Text of my WPF TextBox will be following these events?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I want to restrict this `TextBox` to only take positive integers up to and including `Int32.MaxValue`:

```
<TextBox Name="CurrentPageNumber"
         PreviewTextInput="CurrentPageNumber_PreviewTextInput" 
         DataObject.Pasting="CurrentPageNumber_Pasting" />
```

I have the following events:

```
private void CurrentPageNumber_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
        e.CancelCommand();
    String text = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
    if (!IsPositiveInteger(text))
        e.CancelCommand();
}

private bool IsPositiveInteger(String text)
{
    if (text.Length <= 0 || ((int)text[0] == 48 && text.Length != 1)) // Restricts empty strings and numbers with preceding 0's except for 0 itself.
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = (int)text[i];
        if (c < 48 || c > 57) // Check that all characters are between 0 and 9.
            return false;
    }
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(text, out result);
}
```

This is not good enough, because someone can have the equivalent integer value of `Int32.MaxValue` (`2147483647`) in the text box already, and then add another 1 to the right of it. How could it be possible to use my `IsPositiveInteger` method by predicting the outcome of the `Text` following the event's operation?

Comment: Are you asking how to find out whether the sum of two integers is negative?

Comment: No. Check my answer.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry -- you're asking how to find out whether *one* integer is negative. My bad.

Comment: No LOL, that's not what I am asking...

Comment: I am asking, *How can I calculate what the Text of my WPF TextBox will be following these events?* The two events on my `TextBox` do not give me predicted results as far as I can tell, only the current text being added, or subtracted, which reminds me, I need to update my answer.

Comment: I'd bind it to an int property and stick a validation rule on it.

Comment: Post an answer, I'd like to make it cleaner if possible. I just realized that `PreviewTextInput` is not fired for backspace. Also, it will be a lot trickier than you may think :)

Comment: I deleted my answer for now. Its not good enough, doesn't handle all the cases.

Comment: Do you have a viewmodel?

Comment: Nope, not using one for this field

Comment: Well, I've got a solution that works if you've got a Binding on `Text`, but the Binding throws an exception if I don't bind it to something.

Comment: Alright well its worth a shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117134/discussion-between-ed-plunkett-and-alexandru).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the same as preventing the change to the text, but it's the customary way of telling a user *"you can't put that text here"*. I recommend doing it this way because this is the way the framework supports, so it's easiest, and usually what the framework supports is what people are most accustomed to seeing in user interfaces. What we're accustomed to, we call "intuitive".

When the user changes the text in that textbox, the `ValidationRule` gets invoked. If it returns a `false` `ValidationResult`, the user gets a red error border, the bound property is not updated, and the tooltip tells him what he did wrong.

If you really want to stick with your original idea, you're in for a lot of work, as you found out. I don't think the ROI justifies the effort, but when I was younger I once wrote a binary adder in Perl, so I'm in no position to throw any stones.

The conventional way to do this type of thing in WPF is using a `ValidationRule` on the `Binding`. You don't have a Binding because you don't have a viewmodel. This is a nearly incomprehensible heresy and it chills me to the very marrow, but we'll work with it. We'll add a property to your codebehind just to have something to bind to.

```
public int NonNegativeIntValue { get; set; }
```

If you want to be able to update the textbox by setting that property in your codebehind, you'll have to go the `INotifyPropertyChanged` route. Better yet, use a viewmodel; every time you do anything without a viewmodel in WPF, it turns out you'd have been better off with one. The framework is like a traffic cop; acknowledge its authority and it'll be easier to get along with.

And then we'll write a `ValidationRule`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ValidationRules
{
    public class PositiveIntegerRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            int result;
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(String) && Int32.TryParse((String)value, out result) && result > 0)
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value must be a positive integer");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally we'll fix your `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox 
    Name="CurrentPageNumber"
    xmlns:vr="clr-namespace:ValidationRules"
    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
    >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding 
            Path="NonNegativeIntValue"
            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"
            >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <vr:PositiveIntegerRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I'm making one assumption here: That your codebehind class inherits from `Window`. If it's `UserControl`, you'll have to change `RelativeSource AncestorType=Window` in the binding to `RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl` -- whatever's right.

Comment: Nice read. "The framework is like a traffic cop..." what a comparison! I had a chuckle.

Comment: Indeed, I quite like the way Ed writes his pieces. You can feel the passion, *"...incomprehensible heresy and it chills me to the very marrow."*

Comment: @EdPlunkett Nothing, its a better approach. I forgot about the *is* keyword. For what we are doing, using *is* produces much cleaner code. The only thing to note is that *is* also evaluates for inherited types of an object.

Comment: @Alexandru No harm in that, I believe. My practice with anything that takes object as a parameter is to be as accepting as possible.

Comment: I see now why you used the *try-catch* with the *Convert.ToInt32(object value)* method, you wanted to create a universally generic method for reuse. I can't think of a scenario in which I would want to check any other UI element values for positive integers other than *string* types?

Comment: @Alexandru Me neither, now that you mention it. It's a habit from writing value converters, I guess.

Comment: Important to also consider is data annotations as an approach: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Validation-in-MVVM-using-12dafef3 I quite like this approach. Its used extensively in MVC.

Comment: @Alexandru Oh yeah, I love that idea. IIRC I did that on an MVC thing I wrote a year or two back. Something like that could be very nice in WPF. I'll think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it other than Ed's answer is like this, this way will ensure the UI always has a usable, visible value displayed, but it is not as clean and so I recommend people go with validation rules as the other answer has (its more WPF-like). Also, I had an error with my `IsPositiveInteger` method; originally I wanted 0 but now I realize since I am paging data I want 1 as the beginning page.

**XAML**:

```
<TextBox Name="CurrentPageNumber" TextChanged="CurrentPageNumber_TextChanged"/>
```

**C#**:

```
private bool IsPositive32BitInteger(String text)
{
    if (text.Length <= 0 || (int)text[0] == 48) // Restricts empty strings and numbers with preceding 0's or 0 itself.
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = (int)text[i];
        if (c < 48 || c > 57) // Check that all characters are between 0 and 9.
            return false;
    }
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(text, out result);
}

private void CurrentPageNumber_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textBox.Text.Length <= 0)
    {
        textBox.Text = "1";
        return; // Set text to "1" as default and return. The event will fire again since we set the Text property.
    }
    if (textBox.Text.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        textBox.Text = textBox.Text.TrimStart(new char[] { '0' });
        return; // Trim the text and return. The event will fire again since we set the Text property.
    }
    if (!IsPositive32BitInteger(textBox.Text)) {
        textBox.Text = "1";
        return; // Set text to "1" as default and return. The event will fire again since we set the Text property.
    }
    // At this point the value is forced into the state you want and you can do other stuff.
}
```